# How to associate foreign key to update the column of the secondary table once the primary table is updated?

Tags: sql, qt, sqlite

I have created a program in QT-SQL that has two tables. The area of interest would be to see the DDL - Data definition language part. This is in the createDb(). However, I have updated the entire file for the sake of compilation. My goal is that when the table dttServiceList is updated, the Id of the dttEventList should be updated. I have used cascade here. However, I see that on insertion of record in dttServiceList, the record is not inserted in the dttEventList. What am I missing here? Is cascade rule right here. I am using qt- sqlite. I have tried adding trigger also here, but my sql browser hangs.

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER up1
AFTER INSERT ON dttServiceList
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dttEventList  values (0,"action",1);
END;
```

Another part is, what is the significance of foreign key here then, the cascading part?

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QDir>

const QString dbPathName = "/export/home/hello/demo.db";


class sqlExample
{
 public:
    sqlExample();
    void insertDemoData();
    void replaceDemoData();

  private:

    QSqlDatabase m_demo_db;
    void createDb();

};

sqlExample::sqlExample()
{
    createDb();

}

void sqlExample::replaceDemoData()
{
    /** associate db with query **/
    QSqlQuery query( m_demo_db );

    unsigned int chan = 555;
    unsigned int uqId = 32135;

    qDebug()<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__;

    /** To ensure atomic operations - failure defensive **/
    QSqlDatabase::database().transaction();

    QString queryString = "update dttServiceList SET channelNum = " + QString::number(chan) + " where Id = " + QString::number(uqId);

    query.prepare(queryString);

    if ( query.exec() == false)
    {
        qDebug()<<"Query replaceDemoData Failed!!";
    }


    QSqlDatabase::database().commit();

}

void sqlExample::insertDemoData()
{
    /** associate db with query **/
    QSqlQuery query ( m_demo_db );

    qDebug()<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__;

    qDebug()<<"Insert or replace Data here";

    /** To ensure atomic operations - failure defensive **/
    QSqlDatabase::database().transaction();

    for( int i= 100, j = 32131; i<= 120; i++,j++)
    {
        query.prepare("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO dttServiceList values (?, ?, ?)");
        query.bindValue(0, j);
        query.bindValue(2, i);
        query.bindValue(1, "Action");

        if ( query.exec() == false)
        {
            qDebug()<<"Query Insert or replace Failed!!";
        }
    }

    QSqlDatabase::database().commit();

    qDebug()<<"Insert or replace data exit";

}

void sqlExample::createDb()
{
#if 1
        QDir dir;
        qDebug()<<"Creating demo.db";

        /** create db here **/
        m_demo_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", dbPathName);
        m_demo_db.setConnectOptions("QSQLITE_BUSY_TIMEOUT=100000");
        m_demo_db.setDatabaseName(dbPathName);


        /** return 0 is error here **/

        if(! dir.exists(dbPathName) )
        {

                qDebug()<<"Start transaction demo.db";

                if(!m_demo_db.open())
                {
                        qDebug()<<"Error in opening demodb";
                }

                /** In DDL no transaction is required **/

                /** associate db with query **/
                QSqlQuery query ( m_demo_db );

                /** Create Table for storing user preference LCN for DTT **/

                qDebug()<<"Create Table postcode.db";
                query.prepare(" CREATE TABLE  dttServiceList (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, attrib varchar(20), channelNum integer )" );

                if ( false == query.exec())
                {
                        qDebug()<<"Create dttServiceList table failed";
                }

                /** The Id in the dttEventList is the foreign key and is associated with the table dttServiceList attribute Id **/
                query.prepare(" CREATE TABLE  dttEventList (EventId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, programName varchar(20), \
                               Id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(Id) REFERENCES dttServiceList(Id) ON UPDATE CASCADE )" );

                if ( false == query.exec())
                {
                    qDebug()<<"Create dttEventList table failed";
                }

                /** Do Indexing on ChannelId **/
                qDebug()<<"Create Indexing demo.db -dttEventList";
                query.prepare(" CREATE INDEX pEventId ON dttEventList (EventId)" );

                if ( false == query.exec())
                {
                        qDebug()<<"Indexing dttEventList failed";
                }

                /** Do Indexing on ChannelId **/
                qDebug()<<"Create Indexing demo.db";
                query.prepare(" CREATE INDEX pIndex ON dttServiceList (Id)" );

                if ( false == query.exec())
                {
                        qDebug()<<"Indexing dttServiceList failed";
                }

                /* Transaction complete **/
                  /** In DDL no transaction is required **/

        }

        else
        {
                qDebug()<<"Existing db..open!";

                if(!m_demo_db.open())
                {
                        qDebug()<<"Error in opening demoDb..already exists!";
                }
        }

#endif
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    sqlExample *p_sqlInstance = new sqlExample;

    p_sqlInstance->insertDemoData();

    p_sqlInstance->replaceDemoData();

    qDebug()<<"Sql Function Executed";

    delete p_sqlInstance;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I am trying to add trigger here - but the sqldatabase browser hangs - CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER up1 AFTER INSERT ON dttServiceList BEGIN INSERT INTO dttEventList  values (0,"action",1);  END;

Comment: SQLite has no "OR REPLACE" clause.

Comment: What i'd suggest is when adding the values to the first table, add another query after it to also just add the foreign key to the second table.. an update won't do an insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ON UPDATE CASCADE` works only for actual `UPDATE` statements.
(INSERT OR REPLACE is a combination of DELETE and INSERT.)

There is no function for cascading `INSERT`s.
When you want to insert multiple related records, you have to insert all of them.

Comment: Any other way to do so?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to do inserts without INSERT?

Comment: I want to insert the entry in the other table - dttEventList when the insertion happens on the dttServiceList table. I tried doing ON INSERT UPDATE, but it didn't work.

Comment: how to use trigger here?

Comment: How should the trigger know which `programNum` and `Id` values to insert into `dttEventList`?

Comment: Id is same as what is used in the primary table. The programNum can be left as NULL.

Comment: I am trying to add trigger here - but the sqldatabase browser hangs - CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER up1 AFTER INSERT ON dttServiceList BEGIN INSERT INTO dttEventList  values (0,"action",1);  END;

Comment: I have updated my question, I would be happy, if you can re-edit your answer.